# How to store user account details in a secure way (On a custom embedded system)

Tags: facebook, authentication, embedded

We are currently planning a facebook client for a custom embedded system where it is very time consuming for the user (because of the few available controls/buttons and no touchscreen) to enter his/her account details.

Ideally the user would only need to enter the details once and then they get stored and retreived from there until the user deletes them (or changes password). I've read up a bit on OAuth and the access tokens but as far as my understanding goes, the only way to achieve "configure once" functionality is by actually storing the username and password combination since the access tokens will expire (with the offline token being deprecated this year). Am I correct?

We'd rather not store the user details locally in our device because of security concerns but it seems like we have no choice?

Best Regards,

Ingmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you don´t need to store anything, as facebook handles everything. Only if you have to store user-specific additional data (or settings), you usually just store the Facebook ID only.

Comment: I see how this holds true for a device with a full keyboard or an on-screen keyboard but in this case all we have is a scrolling wheel to enter text, like for example the apple tv input mechanism. Ideally we'd like the user to only have to enter his login details once. As far as my understanding goes, the way to go is to receive a short lived OAuth token, exchange that for a long-lived (60 days) one and after 60 days the user will have to log in again?

Comment: in this case it´s even better with facebook. as long as you are logged in on facebook on the device, you don´t even need to enter anything, you just click on login, click on accept, that´s it. if you are not logged in, you use your facebook login data. in any case you never need to store anything. and yes, the user has to refresh the access token after 60 days - which is basically just another click. but the user has to initiate it by himself, of course.